# Url.Action handling null values or using javascript clientside values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

OK my original post:

[Url.Action is throwing error CS1026: ) expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496963/url-action-is-throwing-error-cs1026-expected)

got answered.  However I discovered that one of the objects in the Model that I was relying on for an ID is null.  I can't figure out how to rewrite this to make it work.

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action(
               "List", 
               "PlacementAgreementAgencyPlacementAgreementsPlacement", 
               new { 
                   Domain = "Placement", 
                   Id = Model.Item.PlacementAgreement.PlacementAgreementId, 
                   agencyPlacementAgreementId = Model.Item.AgencyPlacementAgreementId, 
                   Page = Model.PageNo 
               }) %>';
```

I need something like this (which is currently saying too many characters in character literal which I think might be related to single/double quotes.

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action(
                "List", 
                "PlacementAgreementAgencyPlacementAgreementsPlacement", 
                 new { 
                   Domain = "Placement", 
                   Id = ' + $("#PlacementAgreementId").val() +',   
                   agencyPlacementAgreementId = ViewData.Model.AgencyPlacementAgreement == null ? 0 : ViewData.Model.AgencyPlacementAgreement.AgencyPlacementAgreementId, 
                   Page = ViewData.Model.PageNo
                 }
            ) %>';
```

Have also tried:

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action(
                 "List", 
                 "PlacementAgreementAgencyPlacementAgreementsPlacement", 
                  new { 
                     Domain = "Placement", 
                     Id = %>' + $("#PlacementAgreementId").val() +'<%=,      
                     agencyPlacementAgreementId = ViewData.Model.AgencyPlacementAgreement == null ? 0 : ViewData.Model.AgencyPlacementAgreement.AgencyPlacementAgreementId, 
                     Page = ViewData.Model.PageNo}) %>';
```

But this mix of javascript and url.action is just confusing me.  My issue is that there is no property on my ViewData class that contains the id.. but if I view source on the page I can see that it is being stored client side.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going back to what was originally there and passing what looks like old school querystring parameters.

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action("List") %>?page=' + pageNo + 
          '&agencyplacementagreementid=' + $("#AgencyPlacementAgreementId").val();
```

So not sure if I was on the completely wrong track before and you're supposed to do it this way - or if there was a way of doing it like my original approach.  But it's now working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Jen,

You are mixing client side Javascript with C# server side, not a good mix!

The only way I see you doing this is by putting a placeholder and then do a replace in Javascript, something like:

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action(
             "List", 
             "PlacementAgreementAgencyPlacementAgreementsPlacement", 
              new { 
                 Domain = "Placement", 
                 Id = 9999,      
                 agencyPlacementAgreementId = ViewData.Model.AgencyPlacementAgreement == null ? 0 : ViewData.Model.AgencyPlacementAgreement.AgencyPlacementAgreementId, 
                 Page = ViewData.Model.PageNo}) %>';
```

And then do a [replace in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
var realUrl = url.replace('9999', $("#PlacementAgreementId").val());
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks :) - yeah just started getting my head around MVC and all this use of JQuery/Javascript so it wouldn't surprise me that I am not doing it correctly just yet!!  Challenging for a backend developer